# Created an instance on Azure environment and the site URL

Tags: windows, azure

We have created an instance on Azure environment and the site URL is http://mydomainname.cloudapp.net/

We needs ‘www’ to be used in the site name. as http://www.mydomainname.com

Kindly do the needful and let us know the steps to do so at the earliest.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at how you could map a custom domain to a cloud service: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/custom-dns/.